# Variable not storing the correct value in Python

Tags: python

So I have written a program in python to try and convert a number typed into the letter version of that number. Ex: 323 -> three hundred twenty-three
The problem I am having is that the one of the variables is not displaying the correct value when the process is complete and the output is displayed. The desired output would look something like this:

```
Enter a number under 999: 323
323 -> three hundred twenty-three
```

but instead looks like this:

```
Enter a number under 999: 323
23 -> three hundred twenty-three
```

If anyone can help me figure this out, I would greatly appreciate it. Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function, division
import sys
input = raw_input

n = int(input("Enter a number under 999: "))

if n >= 999:
print("Well, you didn't follow directions.")
sys.exit(1)

word = ""
hundred = n//100
if hundred == 1:
    word += "one hundred"
elif hundred == 2:
    word += "two hundred"
elif hundred == 3:
    word += "three hundred"
elif hundred == 4:
    word += "four hundred"
elif hundred == 5:
    word += "five hundred"
elif hundred == 6:
    word += "six hundred"
elif hundred == 7:
    word += "seven hundred"
elif hundred == 8:
    word += "eight hundred"
elif hundred == 9:
    word += "nine hundred"  
if hundred > 0:
    word += " "
n = n%100
if n == 10:
    word += ' ten'
elif n == 11:
    word += ' eleven'
elif n == 12:
    word += ' twelve'
elif n == 13:
    word += ' thirteen'
elif n == 14:
    word += ' fourteen'
elif n == 15:
    word += ' fifteen'
elif n == 16:
    word += ' sixteen'
elif n == 17:
    word += ' seventeen'
elif n == 18:
    word += ' eighteen'
elif n == 19:
    word += ' nineteen'
else:
    ones = n%10
    tens = n//10
    if tens == 2:
        word += "twenty"
    elif tens == 3:
        word += "thirty"
    elif tens == 4:
        word += "fourty"
    elif tens == 5:
        word += "fifty"
    elif tens == 6:
        word += "sixty"
    elif tens == 7:
        word += "seventy"
    elif tens == 8:
        word += "eighty"
    elif tens == 9:
        word += "ninety"

    if tens > 0 and ones > 0:
        word += '-'

    if ones == 1:
        word += 'one'
    elif ones == 2:
        word += 'two'
    elif ones == 3:
        word += 'three'
    elif ones == 4:
        word += 'four'
    elif ones == 5:
        word += 'five'
    elif ones == 6:
        word += 'six'
    elif ones == 7:
        word += 'seven'
    elif ones == 8:
        word += 'eight'
    elif ones == 9:
        word += 'nine'

print("{} -> {}".format(n, word))
```

Oh and btw, My class is learning python 3 while using a python 2 interpreter so that's why the code has some weird aspects to it.

Comment: `n = n % 100` changes `323` to `23`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since

```
n = n%100
```

mutates "n", you need to "save" the value of "n" first. the most simple method would be:

after declaring

```
n = int(input("Enter a number under 999: "))
```

set another variable to n

```
n = int(input("Enter a number under 999: "))
num = n
```

then replace

```
print("{} -> {}".format(n, word))
```

with

```
print("{} -> {}".format(num, word))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
n = int(input("Enter a number under 999: "))
user_number = n
(...)
print("{} -> {}".format(user_number, word))
```

Every time you do operations on `n` you modify it:

```
n = n%100
```

So just save it in another variable before modifying it (`user_number`) and print it at the end.